# Find handicap based on Team Average

Tags: oracle

Good Day.  I have a new Apex database For a dart league.

I have a lot of work to do! but cant combine (with code - I have the right numbers on the interactive grid by using the sum function) I have the following code and results that work for each player, which I need, But cannot get the summed of average for each player.... this matters when creating a handicap.

```
select Team, name,
       COUNT(WEEK) * 3 GAMES,
       sum(game_1) + sum(game_2) + sum(game_3) points,
       Round(((sum(game_1) + sum(game_2) + sum(game_3)) / ((COUNT(WEEK) * 3))), 2) Average
from score_tbl
group by Team, name
order by 1
```

| TEAM | NAME | GAMES | POINTS | AVERAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B Tyler | 6 | 142 | 23.67 |
| 1 | Blind | 6 | 108 | 18 |
| 1 | Jim V | 6 | 53 | 8.83 |
| 1 | KC M | 6 | 82 | 13.67 |
| 2 | J Spass | 6 | 102 | 17 |
| 2 | Randy B | 6 | 105 | 17.5 |
| 2 | Tim Ketz | 6 | 74 | 12.33 |
| 2 | Todd Lapan | 6 | 51 | 8.5 |

I am trying to figure out the code to sum the Averages for each player by team.

Team     Average  Handicap
Team 1   64.17
Team 2   55.33
etc..

then, if possible compare those averages to find the highest average.  Then take the Highest avg - (each Team) * 90%.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to figure out the code to sum the Averages for each player by team.

Wrap the expression for generating the average in an analytic `SUM` for each `team` partition:

```sql
SELECT team,
       name,
       COUNT(WEEK) * 3 AS games,
       SUM(game_1 + game_2 + game_3) AS points,
       ROUND(AVG(game_1 + game_2 + game_3) / 3, 2) AS average,
       ROUND(SUM(AVG(game_1 + game_2 + game_3) / 3) OVER (PARTITION BY team), 2)
         AS total_average
FROM   score_tbl
GROUP BY
       team, name
ORDER BY
       team;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE score_tbl(team, name, week, game_1, game_2, game_3) AS
SELECT 1,   'B Tyler',    1, 24, 24, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'Blind',      1, 18, 18, 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'Jim V',      1, 9,  8,  9.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'KC M',       1, 14, 14, 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'J Spass',    1, 17, 17, 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Randy B',    1, 18, 17, 17.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Tim Ketz',   1, 13, 12, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Todd Lapan', 1,  9,  8,  8.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'B Tyler',    1, 24, 24, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'Blind',      1, 18, 18, 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'Jim V',      1, 9,  8,  9.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'KC M',       1, 14, 14, 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'J Spass',    1, 17, 17, 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Randy B',    1, 18, 17, 17.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Tim Ketz',   1, 13, 12, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Todd Lapan', 1,  9,  8,  8.5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TEAM | NAME | GAMES | POINTS | AVERAGE | TOTAL_AVERAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B Tyler | 6 | 142 | 23.67 | 64.17 |
| 1 | Blind | 6 | 108 | 18 | 64.17 |
| 1 | Jim V | 6 | 53 | 8.83 | 64.17 |
| 1 | KC M | 6 | 82 | 13.67 | 64.17 |
| 2 | J Spass | 6 | 102 | 17 | 55.33 |
| 2 | Randy B | 6 | 105 | 17.5 | 55.33 |
| 2 | Tim Ketz | 6 | 74 | 12.33 | 55.33 |
| 2 | Todd Lapan | 6 | 51 | 8.5 | 55.33 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7cAB8Gin)

Comment: Thank you, I think this puts me on the right track. a slight adjustment to only show the total_average and shorten the list... Now how can I add something that shows the difference between the highest score compared to all teams?

Comment: Here is my code now so i can test and remove some data...SELECT Distinct(team),
       ROUND(SUM(AVG(game_1 + game_2 + game_3) / 3) OVER (PARTITION BY team), 2)
         AS total_average
FROM   score_tbl
GROUP BY
       team, name
ORDER BY
       team;

Comment: Anyone think its possible to find the difference between the Highest avg and all of the avgs?